# i am confused.what's wrong with my code ? About malloc and function pass pointer to pointer

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, malloc

```
- (void) rgbMatrix:(UIImage *)i toRGB:(uint32_t **)rgbArray{
    int m_width = i.size.width;  
    int m_height = i.size.height;  
    *rgbArray = (uint32_t *) malloc(m_width * m_height * sizeof(uint32_t));  
}

uint32_t *rgbArray = NULL;
[self rgbMatrix:image toRGB:&rgbArray];
```

someone can help？this doesn't work.is that way using malloc not support in objective-c?

Comment: Everything is fine with your code, what do you mean ot doesn't work? Sure malloc is supported in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys.Problem solved.there is nothing wrong with that code above. i made a stupid mistake, wrong assignment such like : rgbArray[count] = 255; which should be *rgbArray[count] = 255;...and this change the array pointer's address..
I am so sorry i did not post the complete code..and thx all you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be passing in the pointer by reference correctly.

The only areas where there may potentially be an issue is declaring rgbArray as null (I think it is safter to just write uint32_t *rgbArray;). Another issue is freeing memory

Comment: I don't get it, NULL doesn't make a difference in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're expecting your method to do (which means that you should likely find a better name for it). I can only speculate you want your array to be filled by the RGB values of the image, somehow. Yet what your method does is just alloc an array and does nothing about it.